# Why doesn't ack recursively search all files by default?

Tags: grep, ack

From everything I can read

```
ack-grep foo
```

should search through all files in the current directory and subdirectories for the term "foo".

However, the closest I can get is

```
ack-grep foo *
```

Which returns all results that have "foo" in the current directory.

Why does the first command not work? I use `ack` version 1.92.

Comment: Is your `ack-grep` the same as `ack`? If so, which version?

Comment: I symlinked ack to ack-grep. The verison is 1.92

Comment: Do you have `ACK_OPTIONS` set or an `ackrc` file? I.e. does it work with `--noenv` set?

Comment: Nothing from `echo $ACK_OPTIONS` | `~/.ackrc` does not exit |
`ack-grep --noenv stuff` does not work, while `ack-grep --noenv stuff *` does

Comment: In general, you don't specify files on the command line with `ack`, which is what you're doing with `ack foo *`.  When you specify files, then you're telling ack to not do any of its magic file selecting, which includes recursing into lower directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is actually in `foo`, or if you have told `ack-grep` to *recognize* it as a `type`

```
# using  ack-grep Version 1.92

mkdir junk; cd junk

echo 'hello' > wango
ack-grep hello       #  nothing found, because 'wango' is an unknown type

echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nhello' > wango
ack-grep hello       #  found, because '#!/bin/bash` identifies a known type
 wango
 2:hello

echo 'hello' > wango
ack-grep -a hello    #  found, because '-a' selects all files (almost all)
 wango
 1:hello
```

---

From `man ack-grep`

> ack-grep is intelligent about the files it searches.  It knows about
>   certain file types, based on both the extension on the file and, in
>   some cases, the contents of the file.  These selections can be made
>   with the --type option.
>
> With no file selections, ack-grep only searches files of types that it
>   recognizes.  If you have a file called foo.wango, and ack-grep doesn't
>   know what a .wango file is, ack-grep won't search it.
>
> The -a option tells ack-grep to select all files, regardless of type.
>
> Some files will never be selected by ack-grep, even with -a,
>   including:
>
> ·   Backup files: Files matching #*# or ending with ~.
>
> ·   Coredumps: Files matching core.\d+
>
> However, ack-grep always searches the files given on the command line,
>   no matter what type. Furthermore, by specifying the -u option all
>   files will be searched.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks; I ran into this problem because I was using ack on coffeescript and handlebars; I didn't realize these files were special. I found a quick solution: http://effectif.com/coffeescript/using-ack-with-coffeescript